# Function integrable over the interior but not over the set

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function; let $A$ be the interior of $S$. Give an example where $\int_Af$ exists and $\int_Sf$ does not.

There's a theorem that says if $\int_Sf$ does not exist, then for a set $E$ of measure nonzero of points $x_0$ on the boundary of $S$, the condition $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=0$ fails to hold.

So we must select $S$ at least to meet that condition. In particular, the boundary must have measure nonzero. But whenever we pick a connected region in the plane, for example, the boundary has measure zero. So I'm not sure which set $S$ to pick here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But whenever we pick a connected region in the plane, for example, the boundary has measure zero.

That is not true, only you can't visualise sets where it isn't the case well, these beasts are very complicated.

Let $C \subset [0,1]$ a fat Cantor set, and $U = [0,1]\setminus C$. Then $A = U\times[0,1] \cup [0,1]\times U$ is connected and its boundary $C\times C$ has positive measure. Take any non-measurable subset $N$ of $C\times C$, and let $S = A \cup N$. Let $f \equiv 1$.

then $\int_A f$ exists ($A$ is open, and hence measurable, it is contained in $[0,1]^2$ so has finite measure), but $\int_S f$ does not exist because $S$ is not measurable.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the fat Cantor set (I've only seen the Cantor ternary before). Why is $A$ connected and $C\times C$ has positive measure?

Comment: A fat Cantor set has positive ($1$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure (that's what makes them "fat"), and the measure of the product of two measurable sets is the product of the measures. So $C\times C$ has positive measure. To see that $A$ is connected, let $\xi \in U$. A point $(x,y) \in U\times[0,1]$ can be connected by a path (straight line segment) in $U\times[0,1]$ to $(x,\xi)$. That can be connected by a straight line segment in $[0,1]\times U$ to $(\xi,\xi)$. For $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times U$, use first a horizontal segment, then a vertical segment to connect it to $(\xi,\xi)$.